# REGEX to find a specific formula in a google sheet cell

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet addon, with custom formulas that fetch data from my API, I built a refresh mechanism to force the formulas to execute again to get updated data, but I want only specific formulas to refresh and not not every cell in the spreadsheet.

let's suppose my formula is called MYFORMULA(), I should only refresh if the cell contains this formula and it has 2 or less parameters, because the third one is always a date, which means it fetches historical data and doesn't need to be updated.

I need a function that given the cell content returns whether it should be refreshed or not:

some sample inputs and expected outputs:

```
=MYFORMULA(A1)   --> true
=MYFORMULA(A1,B1) --> true
=MYFORMULA(A1,B1,C1) --> false
=TODAY() --> false
=ifs(C1=TODAY(),MYFORMULA(A1),A1<>"", MYFORMULA(A1,B1,C1),C1="","") --> true
=MYFORMULA(A1,B1,C1) - MYFORMULA(A2,B2)  --> true
=if(D20="cc",if(B20<=MYFORMULA(A20),"Over","ok"),"-") --> true
```

So to sum up the input can be any kind of complex google sheet formula, but I only care if inside there is a call to MYFORMULA with less than 3 parameters

EDIT: this is what I have so far:

```js
const MY_FORMULAS = ['MYFORMULA1', 'MYFORULA2'];

function shouldRefreshFormula(input) {
  if(input[0] != '=')
    return false;
  var matches= input.split(/[\(,\)]/g).slice(0, -1);
  const splittedArray = [];
  while (matches.length > 0) {
    var index = -1;
    for (let formula of MY_FORMULAS) {
      var formulaIndex = matches.indexOf(matches.find(e => e.includes(formula)), 1);
      if (formulaIndex > -1) {
        if (index == -1)
          index = formulaIndex;
        else if (formulaIndex < index) {
          index = formulaIndex;
        }
      }
    }
    if(index > 0)
      splittedArray.push(matches.splice(0,index));
    else
      splittedArray.push(matches.splice(0,matches.length)); 
  }
  for (let formula of splittedArray) {
    if (formula.indexOf('') != -1)
      formula.splice(formula.indexOf(''), formula.length);
    if(input && formula.length > 0 && (MY_FORMULAS.some(x => formula[0].includes(x)))) {
      if (formula.length < 4) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

what this function tries to do is to generate an array of arrays which contains the formula name plus its parameters so if I find a call to my formula I can validate the amount of parameters. This is not efficient plus I'm not sure I'm contemplating all combinations of inputs

Comment: @Wiktor Title is regex. OP is asking for a regex.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: To clarify I think regex may be the go to answer but if it can be done better without regex I'll take it

Comment: added my progress so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MYFORMULA\(([^,\n]+,?){0,2}\)
```

- `MYFORMULA` Literal `MYFORMULA`
- Borders `\(` and `\)`
- Group 1: `([^,\n]+,?)`

  - `[^,\n]+`  One or more of: Not a comma or a newline
  - `,?` followed by a optional `,`
- `{0,2}` Group 1 repeated between 0 and 2 times

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const inputs = [
  '=MYFORMULA(A1)  ',
  '=MYFORMULA(A1,B1)',
  '=MYFORMULA(A1,B1,C1)',
  '=TODAY()',
  '=ifs(C1=TODAY(),MYFORMULA(A1),A1<>"", MYFORMULA(A1,B1,C1),C1="","")',
  '=MYFORMULA(A1,B1,C1) - MYFORMULA(A2,B2)',
  '=if(D20="cc",if(B20<=MYFORMULA(A20),"Over","ok"),"-")',
];

console.table(inputs.map((s) => [s,/MYFORMULA\(([^,\n]+,?){0,2}\)/.test(s)]));
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this one: `MYFORMULA\(\w+?(,\w+)?\)|MYFORMULA\(\)`

I think it will work provided you don't have nested functions as arguments

The regex above captures only MYFORMULA() | MYFORMULA(A1) | MYFORMULA(A1,B1)

Answer (score 0):

This also requires the input to contain an equals sign

```
function shouldRefreshFormula(input) {
  return input.match(/^=.*MYFORMULA\((\w+,?){0,2}\))/g) ? true:false;
}
```